# F# printf paddings

Tags: f#

I'm beginner in F#, What does %-5s and %5s do in the following code? I thought it gives space paddings but I'm not sure how it pads?

```
    printfn "%-5s %5s" "a" "b"
```

When I tried `printf "%-5s %5s" "a" "b" "v"`
or `printf "%-5s %-5s" "a" "b" "c"`
That gives me an type match error, I don't understand the syntax, It dosen't seem that it is printing the concatenation of the three strings "%-5s %5s", "a" and "b". It seems to put "a" and "b" between the %5s. so why can't I add "c" after? Also, I'm following tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7eNDJN758U

If There is any other good source of learning the essence of functional language by F#, please give some suggesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%5s` and `%-5s` are formatting codes along with width and alignments specified.

The hyphen in your first code aligns the value to the left.

As an example, I have the following 2 lines:

```
printfn "%-5s %5s" "a" "b"
printfn "%-5s %5s" "yo" "hey!"
```

What gets printed is the following:

```
a        b
yo    hey!
```

[Here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/#controlling-width-and-alignment) is a page that explains more about the `printfn` function. The entire site is an excellent resource for learning to use F#.

Good luck!

PS - as for your question about the error when adding the 3rd parameter, the `printfn` function will check for both the types and number of parameters you supply based on the format codes in the string. This is explained in the linked page I included earlier.